# MongoDB: accessing current document for $push doesnt work

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This is my query:

```
 await Users.updateOne(
{ _id: user._id },
{
  $set: {
    'email.isVerified': false,
    'email.current': null,
  },
  $push: {
    'email.oldEmails': {
      email: "$email.current",
      isVerified: "$email.isVerified"
    },
  },
}
```

);

The document has the fields email.current and email.isVerified but it cant use them in the $push pipeline. The query works fine otherwise but why cant I use the reference to the current document with "$.fiel" in the $push operation?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no order in the update operators, and your update depends on order.If you want order you can use pipeline updates with aggregate operators/stages (MongoDB >= 4.2)

Its your query just as pipeline, and with `$concatArrays` instead of `$push`
(i haven't tested the code)

```json
await Users.updateOne(
{ _id: user._id },
[
  {
  $set: {
    'email.oldEmails': 
     { $concatArrays: [ '$email.oldEmails',[{
      email: "$email.current",
      isVerified: "$email.isVerified"
    }] ] }
    'email.isVerified': false,
    'email.current': null,
  },
])
```